# Android Memory Leak - Listview ImageView

Tags: android, listview, memory-leaks, imageview

I have a listview which displays some text and an image. The listview appears to be working fine. But today I realized that there is a memory leak when I scroll the listview.

I'm getting many of these warnings in my logcat:

```
   08-12 17:06:15.037: D/dalvikvm(10826): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3499K, 28% free 36413K/49991K, paused 30ms, total 32ms
```

This is my code:

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

        ViewHolder holder = null;           

        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_item_typical, null);

              holder = new ViewHolder();

              holder.eventTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_EventTitle);
              holder.eventTypeName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_EventTypeName);
              holder.eventImg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgv_EventType);      
              holder.eventLocationName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_EventLocation);
              holder.eventDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_EventDate);
              holder.eventTime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_EventTime);    
              holder.eventStatus = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_EventStatus);    

              convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
        else {
              holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        MyEvent cEvent = getItem(position);                 

        holder.eventTitle.setText(cEvent.getTitle());

        ActionTypes recordedType = cEvent.getActionType();
        if (recordedType != null)
        {                   
            holder.eventImg.setImageResource(recordedType.getImageId());
            holder.eventTypeName.setText(recordedType.getFullName());       
        }       

        holder.eventLocationName.setText(cEvent.getLocationName());
        holder.eventDate.setText(cEvent.getStartDate());
        holder.eventTime.setText(cEvent.getStartTime());
        holder.eventStatus.setText(cEvent.getStatus().name());

        if (cEvent.getStatus() == EventStatus.Active) {
            // holder.eventLocationName.setTextColor(MyContext.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.confirmed));
            holder.eventStatus.setBackgroundResource(R.color.confirmed); 
        } else if (cEvent.getStatus() == EventStatus.Expired){
            // holder.eventLocationName.setTextColor(MyContext.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.declined)); 
            holder.eventStatus.setBackgroundResource(R.color.declined); 
        } else if (cEvent.getStatus() == EventStatus.Cancelled){
            // holder.eventLocationName.setTextColor(MyContext.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.pending)); 
            holder.eventStatus.setBackgroundResource(R.color.pending); 
        } 

        holder.eventStatus.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);

        return convertView;
    }
```

I know that memory leak happens when the ImageView is updated: holder.eventImg.setImageResource(recordedType.getImageId());

I access the images in Drawables.

But, if I call holder.eventImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon1) instead, I don't get these memory leaks. But I cannot hardcode the image. I need to display different images on the list items. Please help me to solve this memory leak issue.

This is the code for ActionTypes. It's an Enum class which contains the image id. I'm only posting half of the items in the enum class.

```
public enum ActionTypes {

Archery (ActionCategoty.Sports, "Archery", R.drawable.action_archery_250, null),
BabyShowerBoy (ActionCategoty.Social, "Baby Shower Boy", R.drawable.action_shower_boy_250, null),
BabyShowerGirl (ActionCategoty.Social, "Baby Shower Girl", R.drawable.action_babyshower_girl_250, null),
Badminton (ActionCategoty.Sports, "Badminton", R.drawable.action_batminton43, null),
Ballooning (ActionCategoty.Hobbies, "Ballooning", R.drawable.action_balooning_250, null),
Baseball (ActionCategoty.Sports,"Baseball", R.drawable.action_baseball_28, null),
Basketball (ActionCategoty.Sports,"Basketball", R.drawable.action_basketball6, null),   
Bbq (ActionCategoty.Social,"BBQ", R.drawable.action_bbq_250, null), 
Bowling (ActionCategoty.Sports,"Bowling", R.drawable.action_bowling_15, null),
Boxing (ActionCategoty.Sports,"Boxing", R.drawable.action_boxing_32, null),

private  ActionCategoty category; // Id of the team for the action    
private String fullName; // Complete name of the action
private final int imageId; // Id of the logo of the sport image in the resources
private  String teamId; // Id of the team for the action    
private ActionSkillLevel skillevel;


private ActionTypes(ActionCategoty _category, String _fullName, int _imageId, String _teamId) {
    this.setCategory(_category);
    this.fullName = _fullName;
    this.imageId = _imageId;
    this.teamId = _teamId;
}

public String getFullName(){
     return fullName;
}


public int getImageId() {
    return imageId;
}

public String getTeamId() {
    if (teamId == null)
    {
        teamId = "null";
    }
    return teamId;
}

public void setTeamId(String _teamId) {
    this.teamId = _teamId;
}


public ActionCategoty getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public void setCategory(ActionCategoty category) {
    this.category = category;
}


public ActionSkillLevel getSkillevel() {
    if (this.skillevel == ActionSkillLevel.X){
        this.skillevel = null;
    }
    return skillevel;
}

public void setSkillevel(ActionSkillLevel skillevel) {
    if (skillevel != ActionSkillLevel.X){
        this.skillevel = skillevel;
    } else {
        this.skillevel = null;
    }
}


// Category 
public enum ActionCategoty {Sports, Games, Social , Hobbies, Fitness;}    

// Skill Level
public enum ActionSkillLevel {  X("Select Your Skill Level"),
                                A("A - Professional"),
                                B("B - Elite"),
                                C("C - Advanced"),
                                D("D - Intermediate"),
                                E("E - Beginner");    
private String definition;

private ActionSkillLevel(String _definition) {
    this.definition = _definition;
}

public String getDefinition(){
 return definition;
}   


}
}
```

Comment: What are the images' size and weight, and how many of them are visible on the screen?

Comment: Can you post your code for ActionTypes?

Comment: Thanks for replying. The image are about 250 by 250 in size. Weight is about 6 KB.

Comment: user2713030, I display about 5 to 30 listview items on the screen at a time.

Comment: Why do you think you have a memory leak? The message looks just like a normal GC message to me. You can profile your memory and see if it gets bigger when you scroll through the list.

Comment: I get so many of these messages (GC) when I scroll. Eventually, the app crashes with this error msg: android - Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x0000008 thread

Comment: But I don't get any of these logcat messages regarding memory issues when I comment out holder.eventImg.setImageResource(recordedType.getImageId());